# MATLAB str2func to send function

Tags: function, parameter-passing, matlab

I want to pass function(string) from uicontrol via my GUI, and how properly use str2func to send function into my m file.

Piece of my GUI.m file

```
function functionbox_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
fun= str2func(get(handles.functionbox, 'String'));
[x, y] = hessian(fun);
```

Piece of my hessian.m file where i want to pass function from GUI:

```
function [x, y] = hessian(fun)
    f = @(x,y) fun;
blablabla
hold off
```

How I can do this kind of method.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your question you have pretty much figured it out. What is missing from your code would be to call `f` with appropriate input arguments to obtain the outputs `x` and `y`.

Consider this code which is based on yours. The use enters a function in the lefthand box and the output (actually `x+y`...just for the demo) is displayed in the righthand box. Play around with it too see how the functions work together. Please ask if something is unclear.

Code:

```
function LoadFun

clear
clc

hfigure = figure('Position',[200 200 300 300]);

handles.TextFunction = uicontrol('Style','Text','Position',[20 220 100 20],'String','Enter function');
handles.functionbox = uicontrol('Style','edit','Position',[20 200 100 20],'String','');

handles.TextResult = uicontrol('Style','Text','Position',[140 220 100 20],'String','Output');
handles.resultbox = uicontrol('Style','edit','Position',[140 200 100 20],'String','');

handles.Button = uicontrol('Style','push','Position',[20 160 100 20],'String','Call function','Callback',@(s,e) ButtonCallback);

%// Call the function
    function ButtonCallback

        fun= str2func(get(handles.functionbox, 'String'));
        [x,y] = hessian(fun);

        %// Make other calculation and display output;
        z = x+y;

        set(handles.resultbox ,'String',num2str(z));
    end

%// Your function
    function [x,y] = hessian(fun)

        %// Define handles. Inputs do not have to be x and y here.
        f = @(a,b) fun(a) + fun(b);

        %// Perform operations
        x = f(pi,pi/2);
        y = f(0,2*pi);
    end

end
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Hope that is what you were after!

Comment: Here is my modification using my hessian function: codepad.org/UR0osWz0 and now how I want to use this kind of data: i.imgur.com/LulAxOK.png. So how change or something my 57 line to get proper result and then paint function in window. My question based on passing normal function eg x.^2+y.2 or other from argument. If you could show me changes, it would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

str2func works a lot like the function-handle @.
So if your input looks something like this:

```
'@(x,y) x+y'
```

or

```
'functionname'
```

it should work just fine.

To pass the, now, function handle to your GUI, you do not need to define it again:

```
function [x, y] = hessian(fun)
result=fun(data);
blablabla hold off
```

---

As for multiple Outputs of anonymous-functions:
it is possible, but, as far as I know, not inline.
Source:http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html#f4-70159

But this is easily solved with arrays.

Comment: I can't write '@(x,y) x+y' because I don't know which function(in this case x+y) user give in GUI  therefore I'm looking for syntax that handle this situation.